# Определение позиции символа в строке

Tags: python, строки

Произвожу обход по строке, для каждого её символа необходимо определять, на четной или нечетной по счету позиции он находится:

```
for s in str:
    if str.index(s) % 2 == 0: ...
```

но такой способ не работает, когда в строке повторяющиеся символы: метод находит первый встретившийся символ, а не тот, по которому в данном случае итерируемся.

Есть ли подходящий метод для корректного определения индекса именно данного символа?

Comment: Не используйте str в качестве имени переменной: это название встроенной функции и типа.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вместо перебора символов строки, лучше будет пройтись по позициям в строке. Из не и четность позиции сразу будет ясна, и символ в данной позиции можно взять

```
for i in range(len(s)):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        print s[i]
        ...
```

Comment: Определенно более подходящий способ, спасибо.

Comment: Первую строку лучше записать вот так: `for i, item in enumerate(s):`, и третью можно тогда записать как `print item`.

Answer (score 1):

Более предпочтительно вместо range(len(s)) использовать enumerate:

```
for i, c in enumerate(s):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        print c
        ...
```

enumerate "преобразует" входную строку в последовательность пар (номер, символ). Для списков и любых других итерируемых объектов это будут пары (номер, очередной элемент).

Это будет работать и с объектами, количество элементов в которых заранее не известно, например при чтении строк из файла.